# How do I display an image from my database in a JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have some problems to display image from database.

Article.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cmr_article", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "name",    unique = true) })
public class Article {

public static final int NAME_MAX = 50;
public static final int DESCRIPTION_MAX = 100;
public static final int FULL_MAX = 500;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = NAME_MAX)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false, length = DESCRIPTION_MAX)
private String description;

@Lob
@Column(nullable = false, length = FULL_MAX)
private String full;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String date;

@Column(nullable = false)
private byte[] data;

@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

Article save:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public void articleSave2(long userId, ArticleForm articleForm) {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(userId); 
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    Article article = new Article();
    article.setName(articleForm.getName());
    article.setDescription(articleForm.getDescription());
    article.setDate(dateFormat.format(date));
    article.setFull(articleForm.getFull());
    article.setData(articleForm.getData()); 
    article.setUser(user);
    articleRepository.save(article);
}
```

jps file:

```
<img src='<c:out value="${article.data}"></c:out>' />
```

Problem is that the image in JSP file is not display, it display code: `[B@6acdfc86` . In MYSQL I see that i save image. How can i change code to see image in my jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do what you're trying to with a raw byte array and JSP EL.  You'll either need to embed the image as [base 64 data as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) or you'll need to save the image to disk some place and supply a URL to access it in the `src` attribute.